# How to Make Background Image in Beaver Builder Row 20% Visible

Tags: css, wordpress

I am creating a Beaver Builder Wordpress site and cannot figure out how to make a row's background image semi-transparent. I have the Theme Customize -> Content settings to a background color - no issues.

In specific row modules (i.e. containing only a text box) I'd like to add an image to the row background, but then make that image 20% opaque. I know that in CSS this should be possible, but as a new page builder I don't know WHERE to add this code. It seems like if I add an opacity=20% code to the Customize -> Additional CSS would it not apply to the entire site?

If anyone could lead me to the right place and the specific code to add I'd be most appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean something like this?
input[type="text"]{
        background-image: url("1.jpg");
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.